# why some ioctl cases always fails?

Tags: linux-device-driver, ioctl

Recently, I am practicing a simple ioctl driver with three commands: print,get,set

In the ioctl switch statement, it looks like this pseudo-code:

```
switch (cmd) {
case "print":
    break;
case "get":
    break;
case "set":
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

But, the print case can be correctly executed whereas get and set case are not.
therefore, I get the output

```
[ 2682.940000] mymem_ioctl: <---Switch Command =27395--->
[ 2682.940000] getdata=80046b01 80046b01setdata=40046b02 40046b02print=6b03 6b03
[ 2682.950000] <---ORG IOCPRINT :test_var=-1095999702--->
[ 2682.960000] <---IOCPRINT complete:test_var=111--->
cmd:6b03, arg=10 success
SETDATA cmd:40046b02
ioctl_setdata error
GETDATA cmd:80046b01
ioctl_getdata error
```

I tried to decode the ioctl command, but everything looks good.

```
getdata=0x80046b01 => 1000 0000 0000 0100 ....
setdata=0x40046b02 => 0100 0000 0000 0100 ....
print=0x6b03

0100 is size of int 
6b is my magic number 'k'
01,02,03 is the number of function(get,set,print)
```

I don't know why... anyone can help on that?

the kernel version is 2.6.38, and below is my code

- [mymemdev.c](https://github.com/nikeasyanzi/DeviceDriverLabTiny6410/blob/master/lab4ioctlDev/mymemdev.c)
- [mymemdev.h](https://github.com/nikeasyanzi/DeviceDriverLabTiny6410/blob/master/lab4ioctlDev/mymemdev.h)
- [mymemdev_ioctl.h](https://github.com/nikeasyanzi/DeviceDriverLabTiny6410/blob/master/lab4ioctlDev/mymemdev_ioctl.h)
- [user-space test program](https://github.com/nikeasyanzi/DeviceDriverLabTiny6410/blob/master/lab4ioctlDev/app-mem.c)

Comment: Please update your question to show valid code. `case "print":` will not compile; you can't use string literals as case labels.

Comment: sorry for making an ambiguous  wrong....  it's just a sample code illustrating the workflow.

Comment: Are you going to update the question?

Comment: Talshorer has given the correct answer, in my driver file mymemdev.c line14 _IOC_NR(cmd)!=MYMEMDEV_IOC_MAXNR is WRONG which makes only  the PRINT command whose NR is equal to MAXNR can pass this if statment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@line 14

```
_IOC_NR(cmd)!=MYMEMDEV_IOC_MAXNR
```

should probably be check

```
_IOC_NR(cmd) <= MYMEMDEV_IOC_MAXNR
```

Also, I beg you, follow the kernel coding style. It would make it so much easier for us to help that way.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/CodingStyle

Comment: i just solved this by myself few hours ago. it's exactly what you said. a stupid mistake. thanks for the info about coding style. :)